# How can I use a variable instead of a id to select a html element in asp.net aspx.cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net

So i want to loop through some html divs with ids like div1,div2,div3,div4 to make changes in them in a asp.net project . I want to use a incremental variable as id names . How can I achive this ??

Code example :

```
 div1.InnerHtml = $"<h1  class=\"cName\">{cat}</h1>";
```

I want to use a variable instead of the div1

Comment: Why do you want named variables, can you not put them in an array and iterate through them ?

Comment: It slipped my mid . Thanks